# Starting iPhone development

Tags: iphone

I have just started to work as a freelance iPhone developer. Earlier I used to work under an organization so I dont know what exactly things are required for iPhone development. I have knowledge about the things but all things are scattered in my mind.

So I am having some questions regarding iPhone development .

1. Is it necessary for me to have a developer certificate before starting developing for iPhone?
2. If I am developing an application for some client , then is it necessary for the client to register as developer so as to post app to the app store? What If post the app using my developer certificate?
3. What  I get in return after I pay 99$ to Apple to run the app on my phone?

My question may seem wierd but I am so much confused over all these things. Kindly bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, if you want to test on the device and not just the simulator
2. If you post it using your developer certificate, it will go under your name/business.
3. If your talking about money, nothing, you get 70% of the profits made by your app. The 99$ is a membership fee not a security deposit. If your talking about benefits, the ability to run your app on device, ad distribution profiles, submitting to the app store, loads of WWDC content, ability to use iAds, and access to iOS beta's and developer forums.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, but you can only use simulator. You need dev cert for tesing with an actual iPhone.

2) It's up to you and your client, it will only change the publisher name on iTunes. Note that each year, subscription has to be updated, otherwise the app is taken from AppStore automatically.

3) You can test your apps in actual devices. You can publish apps in App Store. And also have access to some developer resources.

I suggest you read developer.apple.com for all the details.